# Почему в Map выводит null вместо value?

Tags: java, map, java-hashmap

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Objects;

interface IMap<K, V> {

    V get(Object k);

    void put(K k, V v);

    V remove(Object k);

    boolean containsKey(Object k);

    boolean containsValue(Object v);

    int size();

}
```

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyHashMap<String, String> map = new MyHashMap<>(10);
        map.put("car", "table");
        System.out.println(map.get("car"));
    }
}
```

```java
class MyHashMap<K, V> implements IMap<K, V> {

    private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 16;
    private static final int MAX_CAPACITY = 1 << 30;

    private static final float DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR = 0.75f;

    private final float loadFactor;

    private int size;

    private int threshHold;
    private Entry<K, V>[] table;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public MyHashMap(int capacity, float loadFactor) {
        if (capacity < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal capacity: " + capacity);
        }
        if (loadFactor < 0 || Float.isNaN(loadFactor)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal loadFactor: " + loadFactor);
        }
        if (capacity > MAX_CAPACITY) {
            capacity = MAX_CAPACITY;
        }

        int cap = 1;
        while (cap < capacity) {
            cap <<= 1;
        }
        this.threshHold = (int) (cap * loadFactor);
        this.loadFactor = loadFactor;
        this.table = (Entry<K, V>[]) new Entry[cap];
    }

    public MyHashMap(int capacity) {
        this(capacity, DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR);
    }

    public MyHashMap() {
        this(DEFAULT_CAPACITY, DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR);
    }

    static int hash(int h, int length) {
        h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12); //при незначительном изменении входа
        h ^= (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4); //происходит сильное изменение выхода
        return h & (length - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        if (key == null) {
            if (table[0] == null) {
                return null;
            }
            Entry<K, V> tE = table[0];
            while (tE.key != null) {
                if (tE.next == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                tE = tE.next;
            }
            return tE.value;
        } else {
            int hashKey = hash(key.hashCode(), table.length);
            if (table[hashKey] == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                Entry<K, V> tE = table[hashKey];
                while (tE.key == null || !(tE.key.equals(key))) {
                    if (tE.next == null) {
                        return null;
                    } else {
                        tE = tE.next;
                    }
                }
                return tE.value;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void put(K key, V value) {
        if (size > threshHold) {
            resize(2 * table.length);
        }

        if (key == null) {
            if (table[0] == null) {
                Entry<K, V> newE = new Entry<>(null, value, null);
                table[0] = newE;
                size++;
            } else {
                Entry<K, V> e = table[0];
                while (e.key != null) {
                    if (e.key == null) {
                        Entry<K, V> newE = new Entry<>(null, value, table[0]);
                        table[0] = newE;
                        size++;
                        return;
                    } else {
                        e = e.next;
                    }
                }
                e.value = value;
            }
        } else {
            int hashKey = hash(key.hashCode(), table.length);
            if (table[hashKey] == null) {
                Entry<K, V> newE = new Entry<>(null, value, null);
                table[hashKey] = newE;
                size++;
            } else {
                Entry<K, V> e = table[hashKey];
                while (e.key != null || e.key.equals(key)) {
                    if (e.next == null) {
                        Entry<K, V> newE = new Entry<>(key, value, table[hashKey]);
                        table[hashKey] = newE;
                        size++;
                    } else {
                        e = e.next;
                    }
                }
                e.value = value;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(Object key) {
        if (key == null) {
            if (table[0] == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                Entry<K, V> tE = table[0];
                if (table[0].key == null) {
                    Entry<K, V> keyToRemove = table[0];
                    V vR = keyToRemove.value;
                    table[0] = keyToRemove.next;
                    size--;
                    return vR;
                } else {
                    Entry<K, V> prev = null;
                    while (tE.key != null) {
                        if (tE.next == null) {
                            return null;
                        } else {
                            prev = tE;
                            tE = tE.next;
                        }
                    }
                    V vR = tE.value;
                    prev.next = tE.next;
                    size--;
                    return vR;
                }
            }
        } else {
            int hashKey = hash(key.hashCode(), table.length);
            if (table[hashKey] == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                Entry<K, V> tE = table[hashKey];
                if (table[hashKey].key.equals(key)) {
                    Entry<K, V> keyToRemove = table[hashKey];
                    V vR = keyToRemove.value;
                    table[hashKey] = keyToRemove.next;
                    size--;
                    return vR;
                } else {
                    Entry<K, V> prev = null;
                    while (tE.key == null || !(tE.key.equals(key))) {
                        if (tE.next == null) {
                            return null;
                        } else {
                            prev = tE;
                            tE = tE.next;
                        }
                    }
                    V vR = tE.value;
                    Objects.requireNonNull(prev).next = tE.next;
                    size--;
                    return vR;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        if (key == null) {
            if (table[0] == null) {
                return false;
            } else {
                Entry<K, V> tE = table[0];
                while (tE.key != null) {
                    if (tE.next == null) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        tE = tE.next;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            Entry<K, V> tE = table[hash(key.hashCode(), table.length)];
            if (tE == null) {
                return false;
            }
            while (tE.key == null || !(tE.key.equals(key))) {
                if (tE.next == null) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    tE = tE.next;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        if (value == null) {
            for (var e : table) {
                while (e != null) {
                    if (e.value == null) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        e = e.next;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (var e : table) {
                while (e != null) {
                    if (e.value == null) {
                        e = e.next;
                    } else if (e.value.equals(value)) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        e = e.next;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return 0;
    }

    void resize(int newCapacity) {
        if (table.length == MAX_CAPACITY) {
            threshHold = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        } else {
            Entry<K, V>[] copyOfTable = Arrays.copyOf(table, table.length);
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Entry<K, V>[] newHashTable = (Entry<K, V>[]) new Entry[newCapacity];
            table = newHashTable;
            size = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < copyOfTable.length; i++) {
                if (copyOfTable[i] != null) {
                    Entry<K, V> e = copyOfTable[i];
                    while (e != null) {
                        put(e.key, e.value);
                        e = e.next;
                    }
                }
            }
            threshHold = (int) (newCapacity * loadFactor);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("{ ");
        for (var el : table) {
            if (el != null) {
                result.append(el).append(", ");
            }
        }
        result.replace(result.lastIndexOf(","), result.lastIndexOf(",") + 1, "");
        result.append("}");
        return result.toString();
    }

    static class Entry<K, V> { //пара

        private final K key;
        Entry<K, V> next;
        private V value;

        public Entry(K key, V value, Entry<K, V> next) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
        }

        public K getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public V getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(V value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) {
                return true;
            }
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            Entry<?, ?> entry = (Entry<?, ?>) o;
            return Objects.equals(key, entry.key) && Objects.equals(value, entry.value);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(key, value);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return key + "=" + value;
        }
    }
}
```

Выводит ошибку в процессе дебага:

```
Method threw `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception. Cannot evaluate MyHashMap.toString()
```

Comment: очевидно, потому, что «String Index Out Of Bounds».

Comment: Как это исправить в данном коде?

Comment: @Форс, смотрите [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1557392/386633).  Подозреваю, что в коде могут быть и другие ошибки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Представленный код выводит `null` из-за копипасты в методе `put` при вставке `Map.Entry`:

```java
  @Override
  public void put(K key, V value) {
    if (key == null) {
      if (table[0] == null) {
        Entry<K, V> newE = new Entry<>(null, value, null);
        // ...
      }
    // ...
    } else {
      int hashKey = hash(key.hashCode(), table.length);
      if (table[hashKey] == null) {
        Entry<K, V> newE = new Entry<>(key, value, null); // !!! было null, value, null
    }
  }
```

Для обнаружения этого достаточно было вывести содержимое мапы и увидеть, что после записи одного элемента ключ равен `null`:

```
// Было
{ null=table }
null
// Стало после фикса
{ car=table }
table
```

---

Что касается второй проблемы выхода за пределы строки, то она может возникнуть при попытке убрать замыкающую запятую при помощи метода `StringBuilder::replace`:

```java
result.replace(result.lastIndexOf(","), result.lastIndexOf(",") + 1, "");
```

так как нет гарантий, что `result` будет содержать эту запятую, например для пустой мапы.

Данную проблему можно исправить, добавив проверку и заменив `StringBuilder::replace` на `StringBuilder::deleteCharAt`:

```java
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("{ ");
    for (var el : table) {
      if (el != null) {
        result.append(el).append(", ");
      }
    }
    int lastComma = result.lastIndexOf(",");
    if (lastComma > 1)
        result.deleteCharAt(lastComma);
    result.append("}");
    return result.toString();
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо, ваше замечание о методе put помогло выводу table вместо null.
Я писал тот код для проверки на упрощенной задаче. Подскажите, что могло пойти не так в такой задаче: 
Входные данные: сначала число пар, потом по порядку пары. Затем число запросов, потом запросы в виде элемента какой-либо пары. Нужно вывести другой элемент из пары каждого запроса.
Ввод:
3
car plane
mouse cat
base stream
3
plane
stream
base

Вывод:
car
base
stream

Comment: ```MyHashMap<String, String> map1 = new MyHashMap<>();
    //2 мапа аналогично
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String S1 = reader.readLine();
    int n = Integer.parseInt(S1);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      String Str = reader.readLine();
      String[] a = Str.split(" ");
      map1.put(a[0], a[1]);
      map2.put(a[1], a[0]);
    } 
```
После этого не считывает запросы. При долгом ожидании возникает  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space в строке Entry<K, V> newE = new Entry<>(key, value, table[hashKey]);

Comment: Лучше задайте новый вопрос с описанием новой проблемы.  По коду, представленном в комментарии, нельзя сказать, что вы вычитываете запросы как таковые -- здесь вычитываются только пары.

Comment: Задал, посмотрите, пожалуйста